# Reading values from multiple cookies

Tags: javascript, regex, cookies

I have a js function readCookie which is currently reading value from 1 cookie named test1_cookie using regex. However I want the same function to read test2_cookie as well. What's the best way to do that?

```
function readCookie(name) {
            var result = document.cookie.match(new RegExp('test1_cookie=([^;]+)'));
            result && (result = JSON.parse(result[1]));
            return result ? result[name] : null;
        }
```

I want to read test2_cookie as well. || does not work

Comment: Can you give us an example of one cookie  plz ?

Comment: {"val1":"1" , "val2":"2", "val3": "3"}  --> example of cookie

Comment: A cookie is supposed to set like that : 
"username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";
You'll find anything you need there :
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could use the RegExp `/(?:test[1-2])_cookie=([^;]+)/` which would create a non-capturing group for the test1/test2 match, and then match the subsequent cookie data.

This one would work a little better as it would match any cookie's value in the format test_cookie (i.e. test1_cookie, test2_cookie, test3_cookie.)

`/(?:test[0-9])\_cookie\=([^;]+)/`

Comment: actually I'm looking for something that would match test_cookie  & test_gcookie .

Comment: In that case use this one: /test\_(?:.{0,1})cookie\=([^;]+)/ That would match test_cookie, test_acookie, test_bcookie, test_ccookie, etc. If you want to match more than just one character after the underscore, change the {0,1} to {0,whateverNumberHere}.